# Custom made Drag and Drop canvas in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I made an little test to check out HTML 5.

In my test I have a `<canvas>` and want to drag this one.
But I have a little problem, my canvas is kinda shaking.

Could someone help me plz?

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wnxFK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating layerX and layerY once at the start of the drag helps create a smoother effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/jB5YN/

So at the start you have:

```
var mousedown = false;

var layerX = 0;
var layerY = 0;

function onMouseDown(event)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    mousedown = true;

    layerX  = event.layerX;
    layerY  = event.layerY;

    // Code
    drag(event);
}
```

And when you come to drag you have:

```
function drag(event)
{
     var clientX = ('clientX' in event) ? (event.clientX) : (event.offsetX);
     var clientY = ('clientY' in event) ? (event.clientY) : (event.offsetY);

     var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

     var x = (event.clientX- layerX);
            var y = (event.clientY- layerY);

     var log = document.getElementById("log");
     log.innerHTML = "x: " + x + " y: " + y;

     canvas.style.left = x + 'px';
     canvas.style.top = y + 'px';
}
```

Also, I've moved the events to hook up only once at the start, just feels a bit neater to me!

**Update**

Just for a complete answer, if you want to avoid layerX and layerY which seem to be in the process of being deprecated in webkit, you can calculate them yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/B3TYe/

The change being:

```
var offsetX= 0;
var offsetY= 0;

function onMouseDown(event)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    mousedown = true;

    var left = (canvas.style.left=="")? 0:parseInt(canvas.style.left);
    var top = (canvas.style.top=="")? 0:parseInt(canvas.style.top);

    offsetX = event.pageX - left;
    offsetY = event.pageY - top;

    // Code
    drag(event);
}
```

Andy

Comment: I thought that if you dont press down the mouse, you theoretical cant add an event called mouse move and mouse up.

Comment: +1 and the answer. Could you tell me why my version was so shaking?

Comment: Yeah, you need to be careful with this example if it's going to be used in some sort of plugin which gets added and removed from the DOM, as currently the example doesn't clean up it's event handlers. Also it was shaking because the *(context.canvas.width * .5)* bit in your calculation was wrong,  so each frame it was pushing the left and top of the canvas half it's width in the wrong position. Also, if you think about it, the distance from the mouse point to the top left corner of the rectangle has to be constant, so calculating layerX each time wasn't going to work! :)

Comment: thanks, clear answer :) But you didnt had to remove the mouseleave ;) thats the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use clientX and layerX properties. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wnxFK/3/

```
function drag(event)
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

        canvas.style.left = event.pageX - 50 + 'px';
        canvas.style.top = event.pageY - 50 + 'px';
    }​
```

Comment: I want to pick up the canvas where my mouse begins. Not just random `- 50`. So when i pick up the canvas at the right corner, my mouse needs to stay there.

Comment: just replace the `50` by a variable offset you calculate at mousedown (something like `offset = canvas.style.left - event.pageX`)

Comment: do you do it at *mousedown* and not at *mousemove* ?